# Sequelize.js many to many eager loading

Tags: database, node.js, many-to-many, sequelize.js, eager-loading

I have 2 models: `User` and `Team`

There are multiple kinds of users (in this case Mentors and Moderators) which are differentiated using an attribute in the `User` model(). The associations between `User` and `Team` are as below:

```
User.hasMany(models.Team, {as: 'Mentors', through: models.TeamMentor, foreignKey: 'mentorId'});
User.hasMany(models.Team, {as: 'Moderators', through: models.TeamModerator, foreignKey: 'moderatorId'});


Team.hasMany(models.User, {through: models.TeamMentor, foreignKey: 'teamId'});
Team.hasMany(models.User, {through: models.TeamModerator, foreignKey: 'teamId'});
```

Now I am trying to get the details of the team along with separate objects for all the mentors and moderators that are assigned to the teams. I came to know about the getters and setters for many to many relationships from the documentation but I am not sure how to use the method since there are two different kinds of associations between two models here:

1. Team - Mentor (User)
2. Team - Moderator (User)

How to correctly query for a team's details in this case?

PS: `TeamMentor` and `TeamModerator` are empty models to help the many to many joins

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'm assuming you have N:M relationships between all those models? Like this:

```
User ---mentors many---> Teams
User --moderates many--> Teams

Team --is moderated by many--> Users
Team --is mentored by many---> Users
```

If so, you might want to use the `as` option not only in the `User.hasMany(Team)` that you already have, but also in the `Team.hasMany(User)`:

```
Team.hasMany(models.User, {as: 'mentors', through: models.TeamMentor, foreignKey: 'teamId'});
Team.hasMany(models.User, {as: 'moderators', through: models.TeamModerator, foreignKey: 'teamId'});
```

I think you can then eager load some or all of them during a query like so:

```
Team.findAll({
  where: {...},
  include: [
    {model: User, as: `moderators` },
    {model: User, as: `mentors` }

    // or just use this to include everything:
    // include: [{all:true}]
  ]
}).then(function(teams) {
  console.log(JSON.stringify(teams));
  // oneTeam.moderators: [array of User]
  // oneTeam.mentors: [array of User]
});
```

(side note: I think your User objects currently have a 'getMentors()' method, and a 'mentors' property, that is an array of Team. Same for the 'moderators' property. Perhaps renaming that to 'mentoredTeams' and 'moderatedTeams' would make it clearer?)

Comment: Worked like a charm! I was missing the `as` option in the associations. Thanks :)  Sequelize devs need to improve the documentation a lot! Most of the things are not even documented.